# Permanently blocking a page/URL out of Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a question about filtering / segments in Google Analytics for a unique scenario with one of my clients. I essentially want to block a page URL forever out of analytics --- never see it counted page views, top pages, etc. What is the best way to do that?

Developers added a widget to my client's website which uses an iframe URL from their domain. This iframe is on 30+ different URLs which makes this URL seem like it is the #1 top page which is severely skewing their analytics. I am told there is no other way to do it - especially with the budget/scope of work - which means I need to find the best way to filter this out of Google Analytics reporting.

For instance, I am looking at "Behavior - Overview" - this iframe URL is #1. I know I can click into "view full report" and from there hit advanced and exclude this page to get the real results.

However, is there a top-level filter that can be permanently activated to block this page so you do not have to do the advanced filtering every time you are in Google Analytics?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, your issue is this: 
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012049?hl=en
"Inflated number of pageviews"

If you just want to block it, would this not work? 
In GA, go to Admin -> Filters -> Create new filter -> Custom -> Exclude by Request URL -> use the URI that you refer to.

I'd be interested to know if that works!

Comment: Hi - Yes - Inflated number of pageviews is my problem due to the iframe. I added the filter on the admin level. Do you know when this would 'be live' and will it work on October / previous months' data? For example, I just pulled pageviews for October, and this iframed URL was #1 with over 200,000 pageviews - there should be zero. Thank you again!

Comment: The change may be immediate but you should definitely "see" those changes take effect within 24 hours, so have a look tomorrow and see that you no longer get that page in your analytics data. Share your filter here in case you're still getting that page in your report. For past data (October), I know this is possible so a little research should get the answer. Try applying a segment first to your view, and let me know if it works: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123906?hl=en